# Roundcube & Dovecot inside Docker Containers

Tags: docker, ssl, dovecot, roundcube

I have a Docker stack for my mail server.

My `docker-compose.xml` contains

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postfix:
        ...
    dovecot:
        ....
        ports:
            - "110:110"
            - "995:995"
            - "143:143"
            - "993:993"
        networks:
            - mail
        ....
    roundcube:
        image: roundcube/roundcubemail
        container_name: roundcube
        environment:
            - ROUNDCUBEMAIL_DEFAULT_HOST=dovecot
             # - ROUNDCUBEMAIL_DEFAULT_PORT=993
        networks:
            - proxy
            - mail
```

I also have a Nginx container running as a proxy for all my web applications.  For roundcube I have

```
set $roundcube_upstream http://roundcube;
location /roundcube/ {
    rewrite ^/roundcube/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass $roundcube_upstream;
}
```

With that configuration it's working.  I can go to https://www.mydomain.be/rouncube/ and I can login.  The default port is 143.  So roundcube si connecting to dovecot with imap.

Now, I'd like to use port 993 and ssl/tls.

I tried decommenting the ROUNDCUBEMAIL_DEFAULT_PORT=993, but also using ssl://dovecot or tls://dovecot or ssl://mail.mydomain.be, ... but nothing is working.

When I click on the connextion button, after a while I receive an nginx error page.  In my proxy logs I can see

```
2019/01/31 09:29:25 [error] 460#460: *82483 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 194.197.210.75, server: www.mydomain.be, request: "POST /roundcube/?_task=login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.9:80/?_task=login", host: "www.mydomain.be", referrer: "https://www.mydomain.be/roundcube/"
```

And I don't understand where the http://172.18.0.9:80/?_task=login is coming from ?

With Thunderbird client I can connect on that port.

What's the problem ?

## Edit

Using

```
        - ROUNDCUBEMAIL_DEFAULT_HOST=ssl://dovecot
        - ROUNDCUBEMAIL_DEFAULT_PORT=993
```

I now have a response : connection error to the storage server.

In my roundcube logs :

```
errors: <1db522a3> IMAP Error: Login failed for me@mydomain.be from 172.18.0.8(X-Real-IP: ...,X-Forwarded-For: ...). Could not connect to ssl://dovecot:993: Unknown reason in /var/www/html/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 196 (POST /?_task=login&_action=login)172.18.0.8 - - [31/Jan/2019:13:57:37 +0100] "POST /?_task=login HTTP/1.1" 200 3089 "https://www.mydomain.be/roundcube/?_task=login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"
```

and in dovecot logs

```
2019-01-31T13:57:38.002653+01:00 536ff3507263 dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=35),
2019-01-31T13:57:38.010096+01:00 536ff3507263 dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=192.168.240.3, lip=192.168.240.2, TLS, session=<nVssksCAT7LAqPAD>
```

So dovecot is well contacted but ... ?  Don't know whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that roundcube requires TLS or SSL certificates to be verified by default. Either copy the certificate from the mail server, use letsencrypt to validate your certificate or turn off peer verification in your roundcube configuration.